# Standard.js in Travis CI "Configuration for rule "comma-dangle" is invalid"

Tags: travis-ci, eslint

I just added `npm run standard` to Travis CI. I'm getting this error.

```
> standard
standard: Unexpected linter output:
Error: standard:
    Configuration for rule "comma-dangle" is invalid:
    Value "[object Object]" must be an enum value.
Referenced from: /home/travis/build/project/node_modules/standard/eslintrc.json
    at validateRuleOptions (/home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:116:15)
    at /home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:163:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.validate (/home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:162:35)
    at load (/home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:518:19)
    at /home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:386:36
    at Array.reduceRight (native)
    at applyExtends (/home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:363:28)
    at Object.load (/home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:525:22)
    at loadConfig (/home/travis/build/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:64:33)
If you think this is a bug in `standard`, open an issue: https://github.com/feross/standard/issues
```

In the project itself it doesn't contain much with this file.

https://github.com/feross/standard/blob/master/eslintrc.json

Comment: can u please share the links for the extended config files? I just want to verify the `comma-dangle` rule definition

Comment: It might be this one? https://github.com/feross/eslint-config-standard/blob/master/eslintrc.json#L35-L41

Comment: Added issue here https://github.com/feross/standard/issues/895

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run that command locally? What version of ESLint do you have in Travis?

Comment: Nope I don't get that error locally.

Comment: @btmills I have `"eslint": "2.9.0",` in my package.json

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an older version of ESLint. Some of the options that config uses were [added recently](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/7181) and first became available in [ESLint v3.8.0](http://eslint.org/blog/2016/10/eslint-v3.8.0-released#new-options). Standard itself wants [`eslint@~3.19.0`](https://github.com/feross/standard/blob/37baeac59660e192c04451c2ef6784bda4decb33/package.json#L15). Hopefully upgrading your ESLint version, will make that error disappear!